# Pagination problem - Bad request when trying to use the odata.nextlink

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get all the chat messages for a specific chat id using this graph method - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I am able to get top 50 but when i try to use odata.nextlink i am getting Bad Request error.

Tried through Postman and Tried through TypeScript

Comment: I'm also facing the same error when authentication is using Delegated permissions. Are you using Delegated permissions or Application?

Comment: Yes i am authenticating using delegated permissions as well

Comment: It seems like Graph APIs are broken. I'm not sure if it used to work or not with Delegated permissions :/

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested it and it seems like this issue has been resolved. The MS Graph team confirmed that they were able to reproduce the issue and it's working again now for me at least.
Github ticket: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9729